# writing a mathematical expression in collaborate whiteboard using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

How do I write an mathematical expression  in collaborate whiteboard using node js. Can anyone tell me which API should I use or is there any editor that i can integrate with collaborate whiteboard ?

Comment: What is "collaborate whiteboard"? Do you have an URL? Is it something you are developing, or a library?

Comment: Thanks Amadan   for you reply find the link  http://draw.etherpad.org/d/aayU9bYyjG   you will get to know what is "collaborate whiteboard" where i want to add an equation editor so that i can write an mathematical expression.

Comment: That is "Etherpad", one example of collaborative editor projects. You can't ask "how to add maths in collaborative whiteboard" just like you can't ask "what spices should I add when cooking stuff" or "what is the correct price when buying things".

Comment: Specifically if asking for Etherpad, this project seems to integrate maths functionality into it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_mathjax

Comment: Yes exactly can i  add npmjs.com/package/ep_mathjax to my white board

Comment: No. You can add ep_mathjax to your *Etherpad*. If you are using a different collaborative editor, then you can't use ep_mathjax. If you are okay with Firepad instead of Etherpad, you might use [Mathdown](www.mathdown.net), for instance.

Comment: Hey Amadan do you have any link so that i can see how they used .

Comment: Mathdown has demo at the link I already posted - just try entering TeX (like `$x = \frac{3}{4}$`. ep_mathjax you'll have to install to try, I just found it by Googling.